# Why null value are not consider while apply RowFilter in DataTable

Tags: c#, .net

I have applied the row filter condition in data table. After the filter is applied, the null values are not there in the table.

why not consider the null value, after filtering?

code example:

'''

// Create a DataTable with one column
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyTable");

```
        System.Data.DataColumn column = new System.Data.DataColumn("Col", typeof(int));
        dt.Columns.Add(column);


        // Add 5 rows 
        for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++)
        {
            System.Data.DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Col"] = i == 5 ? DBNull.Value : row["Col"] = i;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
            // Calling AcceptChanges will make the DataRowVersion change from Added to Unchanged in this case
            row.AcceptChanges();
        }


        // Create a DataView
        DataView dataView = new DataView(dt);


        // Changing the Sort order to descending
        dataView.Sort = "Col DESC";


        // Filter by an expression.
        dataView.RowFilter = "NOT(Col = '6')";
```

'''

Please refer the attached images

Before Filtering

[image]

After Filtering

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are sorting the table.  I ran you code and stopped after the for loop and got an empty row as first row followed by 6,7,8,9.  Something else is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When performing a row filter with possible NULL records in the column you are filtering, you will need to perform some sort of check or conversion to allow the NULL values to come back in the result set. By default, NULL values are treated as UNKNOWN values and wont be returned. Here is an example of how to allow NULLS to return in your filter.

```
dataView.RowFilter = "NOT(ISNULL(Col, '') = '6')";
```

You can reference the "DataView.RowFilter Property" article on the Microsoft documentation site for further details.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter?view=netframework-4.8

> To return only those columns with null values, use the following expression:
>
> "Isnull(Col1,'Null Column') = 'Null Column'"